# Antd table columns are shrinking when you add more columns, how to fix column width?

Tags: html-table, antd

I have this basic table:

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Column A',
    width: 240,
  },
  {
    title: 'Column b',
    width: 240,
  },
  {
    title: 'Column C',
    width: 240,
  },
  {
    title: 'Column D',
    width: 240,
  },
  {
    title: 'Column E',
    width: 240,
  },
  {
    title: 'Column F',
    width: 240,
  }
]

const rows = [
  ...
]


<Table
  loading={loading}
  columns={columns}
  dataSource={rows}
  scroll={{ x: 'scroll' }}
  pagination={false}
/>
```

However, when I add new columns, it shrinks to fit all columns in the table area. How do I prevent this, and force the table to start scrolling right, and have the columns actually be the width I specified?

This is me adding a new column dynamically.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a className to your Table component and rewrite inline styles for table tag. By default table-layout is `auto`, you need to rewrite it to `fixed` value. Difference between them you can look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)

So your code will be look like this:

```js
function () {
  return (
    <Table
      className="table-wrapper"
      columns={columns}
      dataSource={rows}
      scroll={{ x: "scroll" }}
      pagination={false}
    />
  );
}
```

Then in styles:

```css
.table-wrapper table {
  table-layout: fixed !important; /* rewrite inline styles */
}
```

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-rumple-b3ihb?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Darn, unfortunately that didn't seem to fix it :/

Comment: Right now the next logic: Table stretches if has free space, but when the space is not enough width of column is 240px. What is your expected behavior? I will try to help